# Insert object in array from another class

Tags: iphone, arrays, xcode, class, insert

I must insert objects to an array from another class. The array is defined like this :

***in RecherchePartenaireTableView.m***

```
self.arraytableview = [NSMutableArray array];

    //Add items
    [arraytableview addObject:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"Type de Partenaire", @"mainTitleKey", 
      @"Tous", @"secondaryTitleKey", 
      nil]];
    [arraytableview addObject:
     [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
      @"Code postal", @"mainTitleKey", 
      @"515800", @"secondaryTitleKey", 
      nil]];...
```

I tried this :

***RecherchePartenaireTypedePArtenaireViewController.m**

```
[self.recherchePartenaireTableView.arraytableview insertObject:cellText atIndex:1];
```

but nothing change. How can I do this? Thanks in advance..

Comment: Whats the behaviour you are seeing?

Comment: Show how property `arraytableview` declared? And why do you think that  nothing change when insert from another class?

Comment: In your code snippet you add NSDictionaries in your array. And what's cellText? May be problem is there. Also you will not be able insert object atIndex 1 if your array is empty.

Comment: I have a tableview that contains this arraytableview. When a row is selected I go to another class (using navigationcontroller) that contains an other tableview. When I select a row from this tableview I want to change the first table view

Comment: I put NSLog(@"sir",self.recherchePartenaireTableView.arraytableview); and I see only "sir" in output

Comment: arraytableview is declared in RecherchePartenaireTableView : NSMutableArray *arraytableview;

Comment: Is it correct how I insert in array?

Comment: Use NSLog(@"%@",self.recherchePartenaireTableView.arraytableview);

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading your tableView after insertion?

You can reload tableView by this method

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

Comment: Yes, I put this [self.recherchePartenaireTableView.tableviewrecherchepartenaire reloadData];
 after I insert cellText